# Do input operands return booleans in c++?

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

Reading through accelerated c++, they give an example I don't understand. It's a while loop with condition (cin>>x). At this point in the script, x has been declared as a double. I understand that the loop executes as long as x successfully receives input, but is >> returning a boolean? I guess I just need a little help understanding exactly what it is >> and << do.... Also while we're on the subject, whats the difference between iostream, ios and iomanip

Comment: You should break this into two questions.  The first part, described in the question title is one question, but everything thing after 'Also while we're on the subject' is a different question and thus should be a different question.

Answer (score 8):

actually, they return themselves, that is,

```
std::cin >> foo
```

is an expression (with a side effect) that happens to return `std::cin`.  It also happens that `iostream`s can be converted to `bool`, they are true if they are ready to recieve input, or have output to provide, and false if they are closed or at the end of their respective files.

Comment: More precisely, they're converted to `void*`, which is then converted to `bool`. And a stream may also evaluate to `false` even when there *is* input available. If `foo` is an `int` and the next characters to extract aren't numeric, for example, then the stream will be in the `fail` state. Call `clear` to reset.